# Remainder of a power tower under modulo $2013$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, power-towers

I have an expression like this:

$$\left(\large 6000^{5999^{5998^{5997^{{\ldots^{1}}}}}}\right)\bmod 2013$$

Then which method should I use to solve it? Please provide the method not the answer.

---

**Editor's Note:** Note that this is a power tower with *different* values and not the same value as with general tetration. Also, don't confuse tetration with exponentiation. Both are completely different.

Comment: In which order should the exponentiations be taken?  My guess is 6000^(5999^(5998^5997 etc ))) but (((6000^5999)^5998)^5997 etc) seems somewhat plausible as well.

Comment: Is there a minus sign before 6000?

Comment: @PrasunBiswas No, $(2013,6000)=3\neq 1$, so you can't just directly use Euler's theorem.

Comment: @user31415, Yes, I noticed that now. I'm removing my comment. :)

Comment: @PrasunBiswas hey!

Comment: @ArulxZ, Hi! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: Work out the answer modulo $3$, $11$ and $61$ (the prime factors of $2013$) separately. Use Euler's theorem to climb the exponent ladder. In the end combine the answers by using the Chinese remainder theorem.